# pass variable to another function

Tags: jquery, variables

I create a variable in one function, and then call another function which I need to pass this variable to, how do I do this?

code at the moment:

```
$('.search-btn').click(function(){
var desiredPage = $(this).attr('goto');
//other code is here
setTimeout(showDesiredPage(), 600);
});
```

then:

```
function showDesiredPage(desiredPage){
// other code happens
$('#'+desiredPage).addClass('current-page');
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
setTimeout(showDesiredPage(), 600);
```

is not correct, it needs to be

```
setTimeout(showDesiredPage, 600);
```

Please notice the missing brackets after the function!
The first line hands over the **return value of your (immediately executed) function** to the setTimeout, while the latter hands over the **function reference** which then gets executed after 600ms! So in the first example your code fires immediately and the setTimeout then tries to invoke the return value of your function.

This is the reason, why you can't hand over parameters in the "obvious" way. If you want to do this, you need an (anonymous) function wrapper

```
setTimeout(function(){showDesiredPage(desiredPage)}, 600);
```

This passes a function object (=kind of the same like a function reference) to setTimeout which then will get invoked after 600ms. Now, inside the function you can call your desired function with parameters in the same way you would normally do.

There is a possibility to hand over parameters directly [(see MDN:setTimeout)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)  but unfortunately this syntax is not supported by Internet Exploder.

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('.search-btn').click(function () {
    var desiredPage = $(this).attr('goto');
    //other code is here
    setTimeout(function () {
        showDesiredPage(desiredPage);
    }, 600);
});
```

This will pass the variable `desiredPage` to the function `showDesiredPage()`.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You need to include the variable that you want to pass to the function().</strike>

$('.search-btn').click(function(){
    var desiredPage = $(this).attr('goto');
    //other code is here
    setTimeout(showDesiredPage(desiredPage), 600);
    });

```
function showDesiredPage(desiredPage){
// other code happens
$('#'+desiredPage).addClass('current-page');
}
```

**EDIT:** The above will pass the value, but the the delay in time will not work.

It should be like

```
$('.search-btn').click(function(){
    var desiredPage = $(this).attr('goto');
    //other code is here
    setTimeout(function () {
        showDesiredPage(desiredPage);
    }, 600);
    });

    function showDesiredPage(desiredPage){
    // other code happens
    $('#'+desiredPage).addClass('current-page');
    }
```

Comment: That is not correct! `setTimeout` takes a reference to a function, not the result of a function. `showDesiredPage(desiredPage)` is evaluated right away.

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen Thanks for correcting me.  while checking I missed to the check the time out.

Comment: @user1671639 It would be better to delete your erroneous code to avoid confusion.